# Accessing index of .word Mips Assembly Language

Tags: assembly, alignment, mips, mars-simulator

I am having trouble accessing an index in a .word. I can do it when it is `list: .word 1, 2, 3, 4` but when I have `list: .word 0x12345678` I am receiving an error "fetch address not aligned on word boundary". Here is my code:

```
.data
list: .word 0x12345678
outbuff: .space 40
.text
la $t3, list
la $t5, outbuff
li $t2, 3
add $t5, $t2, $t3
lw $t4, 0($t5)
jr $ra
```

I am not sure why I am unable to access a specific index of my list. My end goal is to take a hex, like above and output the binary representation of it. If you could help me figure out how to access specific indexes of the lis, that would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Edit:

```
.data
list: .word 0x12345678
outbuff: .space 40
.text
la $t3, list
la $t5, outbuff

li $t1, 0
loop:
    addi $t1, $t1, 1
    beq $t1, 32, end
    la $t2, ($t3)
    #addi $t2, $t2, 2
    lb $t4, 0($t2)
    and $t5, $t4, $t1
    sll $t2, $t2, 1
    j loop
end:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On MIPS, you can't load a word from an address that's not aligned on a word boundary. That's the limitation of the CPU.

In your case, the address in t5 is not aligned - `list` is aligned, but then you add 3 to it. I don't get what's that 3 for. If you want to process byte by byte, you can; but don't use `lw` then. It'd be grossly suboptimal anyway.

If you want to write out a binary representation, load the word at `list` and use shift and AND operations to extract bits from it one by one.

EDIT: you're mistaken in assuming that hex representation of the number survives in compiled code. In compiled code, all you get is binary. When you load the word at `list`, you get an integer in a register with a value 0x12345678 (hex), which is the same as 305419896 (decimal) or 10010001101000101011001111000 (binary).

Anyways, the task at hand is making a binary string out of it. The assignment should cover whether the output should contain leading zeros or not. Let's assume leading zeros are OK - this will make the logic easier.

An integer is internally stored as a sequence of bits. You want to take each bit, left to right, and convert it into an ASCII digit - either '0' or '1'.

In order to take a single bit from a number, you must perform a bitwise AND operation with a constant that has nothing but this bit, AKA the mask. In other words, to check the 0th bit, you AND with a 1, in order to check the 31st bit, you AND with 0x80000000. If the result of the operation is 0, the bit was zero to begin with. If the result is nonzero (in fact, is equal to the mask itself), the bit was one.

The other helper is the shift operation. It lets you loop through bits. Since you want to spell out the bits left to right, we'd be checking the leftmost bit and shifting left.

So to recap: you load your word into a register. You create a loop of 32 iterations. On every iteration, you check the value of bit at mask 0x80000000. Depending on its value, you write either '0' or '1' into the output array.

Should I spell this out even further, or you can translate such an algorithm into MIPS assembly?

EDIT re:code.

You don't have to load the variable on every loop iteration; load it once before the loop. Won't work otherwise, because you're shifting it. The initial value of t2 is 0x12345678, but then you start processing bits one by one; reloading the value would ruin that.

`lb` is pointless. You already have your word in memory.

There's no conditional writeout into the output array. You do an AND, but in a totally weird way. By the way, in your AND command you're ruining the value of t5. And you don't follow up from that AND. There should be some kind of logic that stores a byte in the output array, with the value of that byte being dependent on the result of AND.

And I think you're still confused on what does `list` represent. It's **not** an array in the memory. It's four bytes, AKA one 32-bit word. There's no need to loop through the bytes of `list`, there's the need to loop through the bits.

The whole confusion started with calling the variable "list". It's a wildly misleading name; the variable is not a collection of anything, it's a scalar, a 32-bit integer.

Comment: I am using the 3 to access index 3 which should be 2. I changed it from 2 to test something. I was trying to access all of the numbers other than "0x" and based on what they were, call a method that saved the binary representation of the number or letter to a register.

Comment: I think you're misguided. When you write a .word directive, you don't get hex digits as bytes in memory. You get binary representation in memory - depending on your endianness, either bytes 78 56 34 12 (little-endian) or bytes 12 34 56 78 (big endian). Either way, loading that into a register will give you an integer 305419896 (decimal), which is the same as 0x12345678 (hex). There are no hex digits there once you compile.

Comment: How would I go about converting that to binary then?

Comment: I think you're trying to learn two things simultaneously that should be learned separately - low level organization of data in a computer, and MIPS assembly. May I respectfully suggest that you learn the former first, with a friendlier language such as C, and *then* move on to assembly? It'd be easier this way. I mean, I can spell out the code for the problem, but will you really *learn* from it?

Comment: I know several languages including C and java but mips is a little confusing. I know how I would convert to binary in java but in mips, I am confused.

Comment: What exactly are you confused about in the algorithm that I've outlined? The loop? The masking? The shifting? The conditional writeout?

Comment: I put the code that I have written in my original question under edit.

Comment: I'm still a little confused on how a hex gets converted to an integer. Is it when I load the address of list the register now equals the decimal form?

Comment: The assembler does that for you when compiling. When it reads the source file, it sees the .word directive, parses what's inside, parses a hex string into an integer, and writes four bytes that correspond to the integer into the output file. If you wrote `list: .word 305419896` instead, the end result would be absolutely identical. When the program runs, there's no hex anymore.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to access an individual byte in a 32 bit word, you should use the `LB` (load byte) instruction:

```
la   $t3, list
la   $t5, outbuff
li   $t2, 3
addu $t5, $t2, $t3
lb   $t4, 0($t5)
```

The `LW` (load word) instruction requires that the address be aligned to a 4-byte word boundary.

Comment: When I change lw to lb I am getting an error "Error in : invalid program counter value: 0". I tried to use lb previously.

Comment: That particular error messages suggests that a branch elsewhere in your program is going to an incorrect address. Try stepping through the program with the MARS debugger.

Comment: I accidentally had `jr $ra`. I didn't need it.